# Ethernet connection randomly drops out, have to restart to fix

Tags: networking, ethernet

Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on a Thinkpad T450.

My laptop has a 1000Mbit/s ethernet connection. Randomly, and not infrequently (maybe once a day), this connection will fail and go down completely. If I unplug and replug the network cable, I see in my i3status bar that the network manager seems to think there is a connection, but it is 10Mbit/s and to some random ipv6 address (when I'm actually connected, I'm assigned an ipv4 address).

Things I've tried:

- as noted above, unplugging and replugging the network cable
- restarting the computer - this fixes it, but only temporarily
- restarting the `network-manager` service - this has no effect
- using a different device - my last laptop, an HP also running 20.04.2, never had this issue with the exact same network and the exact same cable

Here's some dmesg output from when I plug the cable in while the laptop is in its 'broken' state:

```
[15592.637139] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NIC Link is Up 10 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[15592.637142] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[15592.637201] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
[16496.379227] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NIC Link is Down           # I unplug the cable and plug it back in
[16499.899600] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: NIC Link is Up 10 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[16499.899605] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

ifconfig for this interface:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ca0a:ea88:f237:d831  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:7b:9d:4b:c7:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 897252  bytes 908329953 (908.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1441  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 113685  bytes 28246157 (28.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1200000-e1220000
```

If any other logs are needed, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: what command are you issuing to restart network manger? I have 20.04.2 LTS and in terminal I issue `sudo service network-manager restart` and that works perfectly every time after the network has dropped out (which seems to happen weekly without any clue as to why).

Comment: @24601 I used exactly that command. No luck, unfortunately,

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.